# How to determine cutoff frequency, static errors constants and phase and gain margin from a bode plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have constructed the bode plot of a system from a csv file containing the magnitudes and phase value for each frequency value. Now I need to determine the value of the static error constants, the gain and phase margin and the cutoff frequency. Since the transfer function is not known, it is necessary to obtain these values ​​from a graphical analysis.

The diagram I get from the csv file is shown below

[image]

This is the code I use to graph the bode plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('example_P3.csv')
data
magnitude = data['Mag']
phase = data['Phase']
w_rad = data['W']

w_hz = w_rad/(2*np.pi)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.semilogx(w_hz, magnitude, 'b')
plt.title('Diagrama de Bode - Magnitud')
plt.ylabel('Magnitud (dB)')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.semilogx(w_hz, phase, 'r')
plt.title('Diagrama de Bode - Fase')
plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Fase (grados)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

To determine the phase and gain margin and the cutoff frequency I implemented the following lines in the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('example_P3.csv')
magnitude = data['Mag']
phase = data['Phase']
w_rad = data['W']

w_hz = w_rad/(2*np.pi)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.semilogx(w_hz, magnitude, 'b')
plt.title('Diagrama de Bode - Magnitud')
plt.ylabel('Magnitud (dB)')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.semilogx(w_hz, phase, 'r')
plt.title('Diagrama de Bode - Fase')
plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Fase (grados)')

# Calculate gain margin and phase margin
gain_margin_freq = w_hz[np.argmax(magnitude > 0)]  # Frequency where magnitude crosses 0 dB
phase_margin_phase = phase[np.argmin(np.abs(magnitude - 0))]  # Phase at the frequency of gain margin

# Calculate cutoff frequency and bandwidth
cutoff_freq = w_hz[np.argmax(magnitude > -3)]  # Frequency where magnitude is -3 dB
bandwidth = w_hz[np.argmax(magnitude > -3)] - w_deg[np.argmax(magnitude == np.max(magnitude))]  # Width at -3 dB

# Plot vertical lines and text annotations for gain and phase margins, cutoff frequency, and bandwidth
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.axvline(gain_margin_freq, color='g', linestyle='--', label=f'Gain Margin: {gain_margin_freq:.2f} Hz')
plt.axvline(cutoff_freq, color='y', linestyle='--', label=f'Cutoff Frequency: {cutoff_freq:.2f} Hz')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.axvline(gain_margin_freq, color='g', linestyle='--', label=f'Gain Margin: {gain_margin_freq:.2f} Hz')
plt.axhline(phase_margin_phase, color='m', linestyle='--', label=f'Phase Margin: {phase_margin_phase:.2f} degrees')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

For the cutoff frequencies, what I do is try to locate the maximum value of the magnitude and find where 3 dB has fallen to mark it on the graph. As for the margins, for the gain, I look for the frequency at which the magnitude crosses 0 dB and for the phase, I look for the phase value at which the phase crosses -180 degrees.For the cutoff frequencies, what I do is try to locate the maximum value of the magnitude and find where 3 dB has fallen to mark it on the graph. As for the margins, for the gain, I look for the frequency at which the magnitude crosses 0 dB and for the phase, I look for the phase value at which the phase crosses -180 degrees. This method seems not to be appropriate, since, as seen in the following graph, the cutoff frequency is incorrectly located.

[image]

This is my first time doing something of this type, so I am completely lost to find a solution to the problem, which leads me to seek help from someone who has done this type of problem, who can guide me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. I think your magnitude is not in decibel (dB); to convert, use `mag_db = 20*np.log(magnitude)`.  (Why I don't think it's dB: I don't think it's possible to have a steady dB magnitude with a phase of -90deg; however, if your magnitude is in "natural" units, it will be tending to 0 at -20dB/decade, but that's difficult to see on a natural scale.)
2. `np.degrees` converts from radians to degrees, which is not the same as converting to hertz; divide by `2 * np.pi` to get hertz.
3. `np.argmax` won't do what you want in `w_deg[np.argmax(magnitude > 0)]` -- it will actually return the *first* index satisfying the requirement.  You need to find wherever magnitude (in dB!) crosses 0; one way to is to check where `mag_db[:-1] * mag_db[1:] <= 0`.  But rather use `python-control` (see below).
4. Your phase doesn't cross 180 degrees, so there's no limit on gain.

Check out https://github.com/python-control/python-control/ [disclaimer, I am a contributor to that project] for a library for doing this sort of thing.  It has a Frequency Response Data (`FRD`) class that should help you.

For help on control theory and related problems you'll probably have better luck at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are correct, I did not correctly convert to Hz. Regarding the magnitude of the bode plot, I have consulted with my instructor and she has confirmed that she was wrong and the csv file that she uploaded is not in dB as we had expected. indicated and that in addition the phase values ​​never go through the values ​​that I need to calculate the margins, that is to say that the data in the csv file is not useful to solve the problem posed. I will try to generate other files and try.